# Excel VBA - Assigning Address to Reference Cell

Tags: excel, vba

I have a range of check box cells and the couple rows above the range automatically list the day of month and weekday for the corresponding month. I'm trying to fill all boxes with a "/" that fall on a weekend or outside of the present month when a button is clicked.

I already have conditional formatting set up for the exact same criteria to make the background of the check box cells grey, and said logic works perfectly. I used a "+" in replace of an OR, and the second argument in WEEKDAY corresponds to the starting weekday (1 = Sunday). Already tried to use 1 in the VBA function but every cell still gets filled.

```
=OR(WEEKDAY(B$4,1)>6,WEEKDAY(B$4,1)<2)+NOT(MONTH(B$4)=MONTH($B$3)) 'Works perfect
```

<s>What's wrong with my "Set refcell.Column ..." line? It's giving me a "Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment" compile error.</s>

Revised code:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    
    Dim rng As Range, cell As Range, refcell As Range
    
    CommandButton1.AutoSize = False
    CommandButton1.AutoSize = True
    CommandButton1.Height = 21.75
    CommandButton1.Left = 218.25
    CommandButton1.Width = 96
    
    With ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
        Set rng = .Range("B7:AF16")
        
        For Each cell In rng
            Set refcell = .Cells(4, cell.Column)
            
            If Weekday(refcell, vbSunday) > 6 Or Weekday(refcell, vbSunday) < 2 Or (Not (Month(refcell) = Month(B3))) Then 
            'Above logic seems to just fill every cell
                cell.Value = "/"
            End If
        Next cell
        
    End With
    
End Sub
```

Comment: ```Range.column``` is [read only](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.column)

Comment: ^ as is `Range.Row`. Maybe if you explain in general terms what you're trying to do, we can help better.

Answer (score 1):

To set a single cell range use `cells`

Instead of:

```
        Set refcell.Column = cell.Column 'This is Read-Only
        Set refcell.Row = 4 'This is Read-Only
```

Use this:

```
With Thisworkbook.Sheets("Sheet1") ' Change accordingly
     Set rng = .Range("B7:AF16") 
     For Each cell In rng
         set refcell = .cells(4, cell.column)
```

As good practice reference workbooks and sheets whenever you can, It will eventually bite you if you do not.

Comment: Thank you! That seemed to do the trick. Edited the original post and now there's just a bug with the logic or something that I've been mulling over for a while and can't figure out why it doesn't work.

Comment: Typically, you would want to ask a new question instead of editing the body into a different question. At a guess, you want ```cell``` instead of ```refcell``` in the ```if``` also unless ```B3``` is a module scope variable it should be ```range("B3")``` add ```option explicit``` to the top of the module to catch such things.